# Move entire layout(with scrollview) over another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

i want to achieve behavior shown on images. First layout is fixed on top and when user want to scroll, second layout(with scrollview inside) should move over first. I try to use Collapsing tollbar layout but it is not exactly what i want. I read articles about that i cant use srollview inside another scrollview but i am not sure that scrollview is what i need.

before scroll: http://postimg.org/image/6hsrmetyt/

after scroll: http://postimg.org/image/po5yplagl/

Comment: This library will do the work what you want https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: @VivekMishra I am going to try that, it looks like what i want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library do what i want https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use coordinator layout. check it out here:
http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator/

Comment: Thanks for answer but this library is what i need https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel